# Two questions in probability.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The first one is :

> In our course we have defined $(X_k)_{k\ge 0}$ independent random variables, $\mathbb{P}(X_k=1)=\frac{1}{2}=\mathbb{P}(X_k=-1)$ (it represents a move at the right/left) and also $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$ and found $\mathbb{P}(S_{2n}=2k)=2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n+k}$.
>
> Then he deduced a theorem (I don't know if it's the perfect constants) :
>
> $\sup\limits_{x\in [a,b]}\mid\sqrt{2n} \ \mathbb{P}(S_{2n}=2\lfloor x\sqrt{2n}\rfloor)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(\frac{-x^2}{2})\mid\le \frac{C(a,b)}{\sqrt{n}} \underset {n\to +\infty} \longrightarrow 0$.
>
> So $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{P}(\frac{S_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}\le x)\underset {n\to +\infty} \longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x}\exp(\frac{-y^2}{2})\mathrm{d}y \Leftrightarrow \frac{S_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}} \overset{law}{\underset{n\to +\infty} \longrightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0,1).$

Apparentely it it supposed to be a particular version of De Moivre-Laplace theorem but I cannot see it in that form.

The second one is :

> We talk about random walk in $\mathbb{Z}$ and our teacher said that there was a result by Lévy which surrounds oscillations of the function (of random walk) in a hull. He mentioned something like $\sqrt{2n\log(\log(n))}$.

It was not very clear, are there any references about this theorem of Lévy ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can find a lot of references in books if you look for 'Central Limit theorem' (first part) and 'Levy's continuity' (second part).

Comment: @JoaquinSan the second part gives just a theorem by Lévy but not for random walk

Comment: sorry about that ... you're looking for the "law of iterated logarithms".